# Racket fold function

Tags: function, scheme, racket, abstract, fold

The following code is a solution from class, not a homework assignment. Given the abstract fold function fold-unit, how do you get to the function count-departments? What do n, x, z and y stand in the count-departments function?

```
(define TEXT-SIZE 20)
(define TEXT-COLOR "black")
(define KIND-COLOR "red")

;; University organization hierarchy

;; Kind is one of:
;;  - "University"
;;  - "Faculty"
;;  - "Department"
;;  - "Division"
;; interp. different kinds of academic unit


(define-struct unit (name kind subs))
;; Unit is (make-unit String Kind ListOfUnit)
;; interp. An academic unit with name, kind and a list of sub-units

;; ListOfUnit is one of:
;;  - empty
;;  - (cons Unit ListOfUnit)
;; interp. a list of academic units


(define BOTANY    (make-unit "Botany" "Department" empty))
(define CS        (make-unit "Computer Science" "Department" empty))
(define CHEMISTRY (make-unit "Chemistry" "Department" empty))

(define SCIENCE   (make-unit "Science" 
                             "Faculty"
                             (list BOTANY CHEMISTRY CS)))
(define ARTS (make-unit "Arts"
                        "Faculty"
                        (list (make-unit "Anthropology" "Department" empty)
                              (make-unit "Asian Studies" "Department" empty)
                              (make-unit "Geography" "Department" empty))))

(define USF
  (make-unit "USF
             "University"
             (list ARTS SCIENCE)))



#;#;#;
(define (fn-for-kind k)
  (cond [(string=? k "Faculty")    (...)]
        [(string=? k "University") (...)]
        [(string=? k "Department") (...)]
        [(string=? k "Division")   (...)]))

(define (fn-for-unit u)
  (... (unit-name u)
       (fn-for-kind (unit-kind u))
       (fn-for-lou (unit-subs u))))

(define (fn-for-lou lou)
  (cond [(empty? lou) (...)]
        [else
         (... (fn-for-unit (first lou))
              (fn-for-lou (rest lou)))]))


; 
; PROBLEM 1:
; 
; Design an abstract fold function for Unit. 
; 



;; (String X Z -> Y) (Y Z -> Z) X X X X Z -> Y
;; Abstract fold function for Unit.
(check-expect (fold-unit make-unit cons "Faculty" "University" "Department" "Division" empty USF) USF)

(define (fold-unit c1 c2 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 u)
  (local [(define (fn-for-kind k)                   ; -> X
            (cond [(string=? k "Faculty")    b1]
                  [(string=? k "University") b2]
                  [(string=? k "Department") b3]
                  [(string=? k "Division")   b4]))

          (define (fn-for-unit u)                   ;  -> Y
            (c1 (unit-name u)
                (fn-for-kind (unit-kind u))
                (fn-for-lou (unit-subs u))))

          (define (fn-for-lou lou)                  ;  -> Z
            (cond [(empty? lou) b5]
                  [else
                   (c2 (fn-for-unit (first lou))
                       (fn-for-lou (rest lou)))]))]

    (fn-for-unit u)))

; 
; PROBLEM 2:
; 
; Complete the following function design. Your function definition 
; must use fold-unit.
; 
; FOR SCRATCH WORK ONLY, USE A COPY OF THE FOLD FUNCTION. 
; 
; 
; (define (fold-unit c1 c2 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 u)
;   (local [(define (fn-for-kind k)                   ; -> X
;             (cond [(string=? k "Faculty")    0]
;                   [(string=? k "University") 0]
;                   [(string=? k "Department") 1]
;                   [(string=? k "Division")   0]))
;           
;           (define (fn-for-unit u)                   ;  -> Y
;             (+ (unit-name u)
;                ;(fn-for-kind (unit-kind u))
;                (fn-for-lou (unit-subs u))))
;           
;           (define (fn-for-lou lou)                  ;  -> Z
;             (cond [(empty? lou) 0]
;                   [else
;                    (+ (fn-for-unit (first lou))
;                       (fn-for-lou (rest lou)))]))]
;     
;     (fn-for-unit u)))



;; Unit -> Natural
;; count the number of departments in a unit
(check-expect (count-departments SCIENCE) 3)
(check-expect (count-departments USF) 6)

;(define (count-departments u) 0)


(define (count-departments u)
  (local [(define (c1 n x z) (+ x z))
          (define (c2 y z)   (+ y z))]
    (fold-unit c1 c2 0 0 1 0 0 u)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `fold-unit` function, you'll see the calls to `c1` and `c2`:

```
(c1 (unit-name u)                     ; n
    (fn-for-kind (unit-kind u))       ; x
    (fn-for-lou (unit-subs u)))       ; z

(c2 (fn-for-unit (first lou))         ; y
    (fn-for-lou (rest lou)))          ; z
```

In the case of `count-departments`, we don't care about the unit name, we just add (in `(+ x z)` and `(+ y z)`) the numbers returned by for each unit such that the number is 0 for Faculty (`b1`), 0 for University (`b2`), 1 for Department (`b3`), 0 for Division (`b4`), using the initial value of 0 (`b5`). If you think this through, you can see why this returns a count of departments.